# What is the right type for any element including document.body?

Tags: typescript

Porting a JavaScript project to TypeScript and can’t figure out what is the right type for any element including `document.body`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: You should use HTMLElement

Comment: @DoronG That is my gut feeling too. I ended up using either `HTMLElement` or `HTMLElement | Window` for my use case.